# Resizing of page when jquery dialog opens causes scrollbars on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery dialog to display dialog box on my page. When i click on button JQuery Dialog pops up but it enables browsers scrollbars too. My default page does not show scrollbars it shows only when JQuery dialog opens. Do i need to set any dialog property to disable web page resizing when showing dialog in order to avoid showing scrollbars when JQuery Dialog opens?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your dialog is bigger than the browser window.

Does it matter that scrollbars appear?

You could use the CCS3 property

```
 html {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

To always show the scrollbar so the page doesn't jump about.